# phpMyAdmin export/import results in duplicate primary key error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, insert, phpmyadmin

I want to globally replace all instances of my site url in the Wordpress MySQL database with a new site url.  To do that, I'm using phpMyAdmin to export the database to a .sql file, then doing a global replace in a text editor, then using phpMyAdmin to import the .sql file.

During the import, I'm encountering a duplicate entry for primary key error.  Trying to debug this, I exported the file, then imported the identical file, making no changes and I still get the same error.

I appreciate any help solving this.

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_comments`
--
INSERT INTO  `wp_comments` 
  (`comment_ID`, `comment_post_ID`, `comment_author`, `comment_author_email`
  ,`comment_author_url`, `comment_author_IP`, `comment_date`, `comment_date_gmt` 
  ,`comment_content`, `comment_karma`, `comment_approved`, `comment_agent` 
  ,`comment_type`, `comment_parent`, `user_id`) 
VALUES (1, 1, 'Mr WordPress', ''
       ,'http://wordpress.org/', '', '2011-04-28 00:49:55', '2011-04-28 00:49:55'
       ,'Hi, this is a comment.<br />To delete a comment, 
         just log in and view the post&#039;s comments. 
         There you will have the option to edit or delete them.'
       , 0, 'post-trashed',  '',  '', 0, 0 ) ;

MySQL said: 

#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: @Johan - thanks for the edit to make the code in my question more legible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original data is still in the database.

If you were working manually you'd send a `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT` query with the new values, but since you're doing a batch import, it may just be better to wipe the existing table clean before the import.

```
DELETE FROM `tblName`;
```

Be sure to back-up your data, first.

Comment: thanks.  In fact, in my case I think I can delete the entire database before doing an import.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid duplicates you have to use UPDATE instead of INSERT statements. To achieve this in phpMyAdmin, follow these steps:

1. Select your database in the tree.
2. OPTIONAL. Go to "Search" tab and search for string you want to replace in all tables. If string is found in several tables only, note their names. This will help to speed up process by updating only the tables which needs updating. This my be important if you have lot of data.
3. Go to "Export" tab.
4. In the "Export method:" select "Custom".
5. OPTIONAL. If you noted the tables which need updating in step 2 above, then in the "Table(s):" section, click "Unselect all" and then select only the tables which need to be updated.
6. Scroll down to "Data creation options" section, and in the drop
       box labeled "Function to use when dumping data:" select "UPDATE"
       (default is "INSERT").
7. Click "Go".
8. Open the downloaded SQL dump file.
9. IMPORTANT! Save the file with a new name for backup purposes before any changes are made.
10. Use Search & replace function of your editor to change what you want. Then save the file.
11. In phpMyAdmin go to "Import" tab.
12. In the "File to import:" section click the "Choose file" button and
     browse for the edited file. Click GO

You are ready! To check if everything is OK, search the database second time (repeat step 2). You should not find any tables containing your old string.

Comment: With some large Wordpress files, I was getting the Primary Key duplicate error, your answer did the trick !

Comment: Thanks George. Using this method I still received the warning about Primary Key duplicate, but all of the strings were replaced as expected.

So, in this case, I guess we can just ignore the message about primary key duplicates, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you're exporting, that means that the main content stays in the database. So, when you try to insert a new row with the same PRIMARY KEY, which are always UNIQUE, you'll get an error.

Solution: You must delete the row from the table that has the same comment_ID.
You must open the PHPMyAdmin and go your table page, and check the row with the ID you want. In this case is 1, which means that it is probabily in the first results page of your table listing. Just click on the red X which appears in the row.

This could also be done by SQL, which could be simple too.

```
DELETE FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

For this, just select your database in PHPMyAdmin and go to the SQL tab, and insert the code above in the text area.

Comment: You don't **have to** delete the row, just to an `insert ... on duplicate key update` (see answer below).

Comment: @Scorch, OK what steps would I have to follow in phpmyAdmin, I wouldn't know that reading your answer.

Comment: @Johan I didn't give the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE solution, because that would just update the unnecessary (old) row, not delete it. Which means the it will create to comments, because the old would remain. About the post, I have edited it. I'm new here and I didn0t think that it would be necessary a step-by-step description. My apologies. :)

Comment: Have fun doing this in turn for every single row that you're re-importing.

Comment: @Scorch: I think you've misunderstood what `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does. It updates; it does not ignore. You wouldn't get two of the same comment.

Comment: @Scorch, updating overwrites data, it does not add an extra copy somewhere, so I'm confused as to where `the old would remain`. On a sidenote the `limit 1` is not needed here, as `comment_id` is the primary key and as such is always unique, including `limit 1` as a habit to prevent runaway deletes is not a bad idea though.

Comment: @Johan Ok, I thought it would just update the old ID to do not collide with the new one, but I have searched the web ad found that such info is wrong (and you're right :D). I'm really sorry for the confusion. :(

Comment: @Johan Ok, I thought it would just update the old ID to do not collide with the new one, but I have searched the web ad found that such info is wrong (and you're right :D). I'm really sorry for the confusion. :(

Comment: @Scorch - thanks for the help. I ended up deleting entire table before I did the import.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and error number. Deleted the database, recreate with no tables, and import the changed export file worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related with your file - you are trying to create a DB using a copy - at the top of your file you will find something like this:

**CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `*THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_DB*` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
USE `*THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_DB*`;**

and I'm sure that you already have a DB with this name - IN THE SAME SERVER - please check, because you are trying to overwrite!!  Just change the name OR (better) ERASE THIS LINE!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have that record there, you can just update the record rather than inserting.  It would go something like this.

```
  UPDATE `wp_comments` 
  SET 'comment_author_url' = 'YOUR NEW ADDRESS'
  WHERE  `comment_ID` = 1
```

Just update every instance of your old address using this method.  You can search through all of all posts by saying "WHERE 'comment_author_url' = 'YOUR OLD ADDRESS'"

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is replace your URL, I believe this is all you must do:

```
Update `wp_comments` Set 
`comment_author_url` = 'http://wordpress.org/'
Where `comment_author` = 'Mr WordPress'
```

Just type the above SQL into PHPMyAdmin's SQL box and execute.

NOTE: First make sure you have a backup. And there's no need to do all that export and import stuff :)

Comment: the URL is peppered throughout the database in many different tables.  It's a WordPress thing.  When I did a global text replace in the text editor, it replaced 215 occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Change to code to

```
INSERT .... (what you already have) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;
```

This will fix your problem with a minimum of fuss, whilst still inserting new rows.

Comment: My answer is optimised for the use of batch export/import tools, like the one in phpmyadmin. Even speaking strictly semantically, the OP _wants_ a fresh start, and not potential old data lying around. I'd even recommend dropping and recreating the tables, frankly.

Comment: @Tomalak, That may of may not be possible depending on foreign key constraints.

Comment: [Wordpress tables are MyISAM](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/whuy-myisam) (unless explicitly converted). MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys.

Comment: @Tomalak, OK makes sense given the fulltext searches wp would need.